# How to ugrade to openssl 1.0.2 within ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, openssl

I need to upgrade Openssl to 1.0.2 to get a certain feature. This worked following this tutorial http://www.miguelvallejo.com/updating-to-openssl-1-0-2g-on-ubuntu-server-12-04-14-04-lts-to-stop-cve-2016-0800-drown-attack/  However, HAProxy for example is still built with the old openssl version and thus does not support the ssl feature I need

How do I upgrade without compiling? I tried apt-get update and upgrade and also dist-upgrade. All that did not bring me to version 1.0.2

Comment: You need to find a version of HAProxy that is linked to the newer version of the OpenSSL library. If one does not exist, then you have to recompile it.

Comment: Does Ubuntu not backport security fixes to it's LTS environments ? Check the release notes for your installed openssl - it may have the patches applied.

Comment: Use a distribution that shipped with OpenSSL 1.0.2. It is extremely unsafe to attempt to replace critical path libraries such as this, and the premise behind that Internet tutorial is wrong, making it pretty useless.

Comment: Well replacing ubuntu 14.04 Lts or uprgrading it is out of question. It is a server cluster and this would result in way to much work/cost. Is there not another way? My goal is to upgrade to HTTP/2 which needs OpenSSL 1.0.2

Comment: Says "sudo apt-get install php5-curl (Install cURL library)"?

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned [here](https://www.openssl.org/source/), this openssl 1.0.2 is supported till 31st December, 2019

1. Download source from https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.2n.tar.gz
2. Extract it to a folder
3. Go to the extracted folder and use the following command

   ```
   sudo ./config && sudo make && sudo make install
   ```
4. It will take some time to install
5. Link the newly installed openssl

   ```
   sudo ln -sf /usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl `which openssl`
   ```
6. Check the version and make sure that it is installed.

   ```
   openssl version -v
   ```

Comment: ...Sort of...Python doesn't seem to be able to use it, so `pip` installs fail.

Comment: Solution: forget about Python 3.7 and just install Python 3.6.6 instead! Installation instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44758621/4561887. This way, we forego the whole necessity of having openssl 1.0.2 (I no longer need it) and `pip` just works!

Answer (score 1):

This article has a complete answer. 
https://www.miguelvallejo.com/tag/installing-openssl-1-0-2g-on-ubuntu/

> cURL Method
>
> sudo apt-get install php5-curl (Install cURL library)
>   sudo apt-get install make (Install compiling library Make)
>   curl https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.2l.tar.gz | tar xz && cd openssl-1.0.2l && sudo ./config && sudo make && sudo make install (single command that will download latest binaries, extract them, cd into the directory, compile configuration and then install the files)
>   sudo ln -sf /usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl ‘which openssl’ (This will create a sym link to the new binaries)
>   openssl version -v (Used to check the version of the Current OpenSSL binaries)
>
> wget method
>
> sudo apt-get install make (Install compiling library Make)
>   wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.2l.tar.gz (Download the latest OpenSSL 1.0.2g binaries)
>   tar -xzvf openssl-1.0.2l.tar.gz (Extract the tar ball to the local directory)
>   cd openssl-1.0.2l (Enter extracted OpenSSL directory)
>   sudo ./config (Configure binaries for compiling)
>   sudo make install (install configured binaries)
>   sudo ln -sf /usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl `which openssl` (This will create a sym link to the new binaries)
>   openssl version -v (Used to check the version of the Current OpenSSL binaries)

Answer (score -1):

You might need this to install "add-apt-repository":

> sudo apt-get update && apt-get install -y software-properties-common

This will get you up to v1.0.2g without the need to compile:

> openssl version -a
>   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:0k53d-karl-f830m/openssl
>   sudo apt-get update
>   sudo apt-get install openssl
>   openssl version -a

Comment: Adding a non-official repository for security software like OpenSSL is highly questionable and should be avoided.